# Ovewirte property value in json schema Using AJV

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I've the following schema

```
var schema = {
    "$id": "postClientSchema.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {},
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "dynamicDefaults": {
        "Type": "gettype"
    },
    "properties": {
        "ID": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "Name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Type": {
            "type": "integer"
        }

    }
}
```

I wish to overwrite the value of Type in incoming payload by the value I get from dynamicDefaults. `gettype` is a custom function which returns me value for `type` property.

I'm using AJV for schema validation.
Thank you

Comment: I think you're asusming JSON Schema does something it does not. JSON Schema is for validating JSON. It does not do anything TO the JSON instance being validated.

Comment: Thank you @Relequestual. But I wish if I could bring this functionality to my schema using AJV

Comment: If you want more advanced validation, you might consider looking for a JSON validation library.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Advance Schema Validator (AJV) and I wonder if AJV can do that.

Comment: You cannot do this with using JSON Schema. You need to use something else to validate your JSON in the way you want.

Comment: Okay. can you tell me if my json schema validator(  AJV: Another JSON Schema Validator -- for NodeJs) do this??

Comment: "You cannot do this with using JSON Schema." - That means, anything that uses JSON Schema to do validation, WILL NOT do what you want. You need something that DOES NOT use JSON Schema to do what you want.